# CSS Webkit Appearance Override?

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to override the -webkit specific CSS to show a form element. Is this possible?

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Does anyone know if you can do... show or block or display or something?

```
-webkit-appearance: show; 

-webkit-appearance: block;
```

Comment: maybe ignore or something?

Comment: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[css-infos.net](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance) lists the values as:

```
caps-lock-indicator The indicator that appears in a password field when Caps Lock is active. Available in Safari 4.0 and later. Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
button  
button-bevel    
caret   
checkbox    
default-button  
listbox 
listitem    
media-fullscreen-button 
media-mute-button   
media-play-button   
media-seek-back-button  
media-seek-forward-button   
media-slider    
media-sliderthumb   
menulist    
menulist-button 
menulist-text   
menulist-textfield  
none    
push-button 
radio   
searchfield 
searchfield-cancel-button   
searchfield-decoration  
searchfield-results-button  
searchfield-results-decoration  
slider-horizontal, slider-vertical  
sliderthumb-horizontal  
sliderthumb-vertical    
square-button   
textarea    
textfield   
scrollbarbutton-down    Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbarbutton-left    Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbarbutton-right   Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbarbutton-up  Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbargripper-horizontal Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbargripper-vertical   Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbarthumb-horizontal   Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbarthumb-vertical Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbartrack-horizontal   Unsupported in Safari 4.0
scrollbartrack-vertical Unsupported in Safari 4.0
```